# Is there a SELF pointer for blocks?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, objective-c-blocks

I'd like to recursively call a block from within itself. In an obj-c object, we get to use "self", is there something like this to refer to a block instance from inside itself?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Fun story! Blocks actually are Objective-C objects. That said, there is no exposed API to get the `self` pointer of blocks.

However, if you declare blocks before using them, you can use them recursively. In a non-garbage-collected environment, you would do something like this:

```
__weak __block int (^block_self)(int);
int (^fibonacci)(int) = [^(int n) {
    if (n < 2) { return 1; }
    return block_self(n - 1) + block_self(n - 2);
} copy];

block_self = fibonacci;
```

It is **necessary** to apply the `__block` modifier to `block_self`, because otherwise, the `block_self` reference inside `fibonacci` would refer to it before it is assigned (crashing your program on the first recursive call). The `__weak` is to ensure that the block doesn't capture a strong reference to itself, which would cause a memory leak.

Comment: Excellent answer. the __block modifier would have taken me awhile to figure out on my own. Thanks a ton! Rep to you!

Comment: If you pass it to a function that will end up copying it (such as `dispatch_async()`), you also need to copy the block in the scope of the assignment.

Comment: This code will leak, even if you have a termination condition. Add a countdown variable and run it through Instruments leak checker to see. Also, the compiler will issue the following warning if you have the right warnings turned on: "Capturing 'myBlock' in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle"

Comment: @Karl, I guess I was using garbage collection when I wrote this. What is your solution then?

Comment: I'll take another stab at it tonight or tomorrow. I've only managed to come up with an ugly hack so far.

Comment: @Karl any interesting developments in the last couple of years?

Comment: @Stavash, see answer below.

Answer (score 14):

The following recursive block code will compile and run using ARC, GC, or manual memory management, without crashing, leaking, or issuing warnings (analyzer or regular):

```
typedef void (^CountdownBlock)(int currentValue);

- (CountdownBlock) makeRecursiveBlock
{
    CountdownBlock aBlock;
    __block __unsafe_unretained CountdownBlock aBlock_recursive;
    aBlock_recursive = aBlock = [^(int currentValue)
    {
        if(currentValue >= 0)
        {
            NSLog(@"Current value = %d", currentValue);
            aBlock_recursive(currentValue-1);
        }
    } copy];
#if !__has_feature(objc_arc)
    [aBlock autorelease];
#endif

    return aBlock;
}

- (void) callRecursiveBlock
{
    CountdownBlock aBlock = [self makeRecursiveBlock];

    // You don't need to dispatch; I'm doing this to demonstrate
    // calling from beyond the current autorelease pool.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                   {
                       aBlock(10);
                   });
}
```

Important considerations:

- You must copy the block onto the heap manually or else it will try to access a nonexistent stack when you call it from another context (ARC usually does this for you, but not in all cases. Better to play it safe).
- You need TWO references: One to hold the strong reference to the block, and one to hold a weak reference for the recursive block to call (technically, this is only needed for ARC).
- You must use the __block qualifier so that the block doesn't capture the as-yet unassigned value of the block reference.
- If you're doing manual memory management, you'll need to autorelease the copied block yourself.

Comment: This wouldn't work in ARC, but what about ```copy] autorelease]``` instead of just copy, so you don't have to call release inside the block? For ARC maybe doing ```aBlock = nil``` after calling ```aBlock(10);``` ?

Comment: Actually, upon revisiting this solution, it turns out that holding the reference inside the block would cause a leak if the block didn't get called. I've now updated the answer so that it works properly whether you call it or not.

Comment: I have a problem that adds a layer of complexity to this, but I'm not entirely sure my problem is solvable. I'd like to be able to retry API calls through AFNetworking. I think this pastebin simplifies and illustrates the problem. http://pastebin.com/xRPJuckZ The unsafe_unretained recursive block is called from inside another block inside itself, and calling it there leads to a bad access exception. Would you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: aBlock is the one holding the strong reference, so once it falls out of scope (in the calling function you returned it to), it gets released, and your inner unsafe_unretained reference becomes invalid. You would need to devise a way to hold the strong reference until you're sure you don't need it anymore. You might be able to do "__block RetryAPICall aBlock", and then conditionally set it to nil inside the block. I'm not sure if that will work, though.

Answer (score 6):

You have to declare the block variable as `__block`:

```
typedef void (^MyBlock)(id);

__block MyBlock block = ^(id param) {
  NSLog(@"%@", param);
  block(param);
};
```

Comment: @Joe Blow [`__block` specifically is a keyword](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW6).

Comment: This code will also leak for the same reason as zneak's code.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `self` for blocks (yet). You can build one like this (assuming ARC):

```
__block void (__weak ^blockSelf)(void);
void (^block)(void) = [^{
        // Use blockSelf here
} copy];
blockSelf = block;
    // Use block here
```

The `__block` is needed so we can set `blockSelf` to the block after creating the block. The `__weak` is needed because otherwise the block would hold a strong reference to itself, which would cause a strong reference cycle and therefore a memory leak. The `copy` is needed to make sure that the block is copied to the heap. That may be unnecessary with newer compiler versions, but it won't do any harm.